# Python comparing elements in two different lists

Tags: python, for-loop

Currently I am able to print out the dictionary items that have a match in the sentences list. I would rather like to print out the elements of the sentences list. Kindly advice the best way to accomplish this. Below is my code. Thank you.

```
sentences = "The book was awesome and envious","splendid job done by those guys", "that was an amazing sale"

dictionary = "awesome","amazing", "fantastic","envious"

##Find Matches
for match in dictionary:
    if any(match in value for value in sentences):
        print match
```

Comment: You seem to be matching sentences against words - are you sure that's right?

Comment: thats what I thought so I put it as my answer ... but im not sure I understand his problem statement ...

Comment: I have two lists:
a - dictionary which contains keywords such as ["impeccable", "obvious", "fantastic", "evident"] as elements of the list

b - sentences which contains sentences such as ["I am impeccable", "you are fantastic", "that is obvious", "that is evident"]

The goal is to use the dictionary list as a reference.

The process is as follows:

Take an element for the sentences list and run it against each element in the dictionary list. If any of the elements exists, then spit out that sentence to a new list
Repeating step 1 for each of the elements in the sentences list.

Comment: edited my answer so that it assumes you have a list of sentences ...

Answer (score 1):

```
all_words = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]","",main_text).split()
dictionary_words = open("dictionary.txt").read().split()

print "words found:",set(all_words).intersection(dictionary_words)
print "words not found:",set(all_words).difference(dictionary_words)
```

is that what you are lookign for?

if you have a list of sentences and you want to create a new list with sentences that contain dictionary words you can do something like

```
sentances_with_words_in_dict = [sentence for sentence in all_sentences if set(sentence.split()).intersection(dictionary_words)]
```

Comment: awesome. I will give this a go and let you know. Thanks mucho for the helpo.

Comment: Hello Joran, I tried your suggestion but run into an unending loop. The problem is from me. I think I over complicated my request. I have edited the code for simplification. Please see above.